# Guardar registros de QUERY en array DELPHI

Tags: sql, array, sqlite, delphi

Estoy comenzando con base de datos (SQLite).
Estoy utilizando componentes FIREDAC.

Como no encontre componentes datacontrols, en delphi 10.4, lo que quiero realizar es guardar los datos(tipo string) yo mismo en un array.

```
QUERY.SQL.TEXT := ´SELECT NOMBRES FROM database1´;
QUERY.OPEN();
VECTOR[1] := query.fieldbyname(´NOMBRES´).asString;
```

El problema es que solo me estaría mostrando 1 registro.
¿Como debo proceder para recorrer varios registros y guardarlos en el array?
Para luego yo poder mostrarlos como quiera realizando un array tipo record por ejemplo.

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Publiqué una respuesta, que no abarca todo, pues tu publicación tiene varias preguntas, y eso no es aceptable en StackOverflow, la regla es una pregunta por publicación. Te invito a visitar el centro de ayuda y/o hacer el recorrido.  Un saludo.

Comment: Si alguna de las respuestas te ha sido útil, recuera votarla para que otros usuarios pueda serles útil.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para recorrer un DataSet, puedes valerte de los métodos `Next`, para ir al siguiente registro y `Eof`, que te indica si has terminado de recorrer un DataSet (se enciende cuando invocas a Next en el último registro), por ejemplo, con un ciclo while harías algo así...

```
Query.SQL.Text := 'select * from Tabla1';
Query.Open;
while not Query.Eof do
begin
  //lo que quieras hacer con los datos de cada registro
  Query.Next;
end;
```

Sobre tu afirmación de no haber encontrado componentes "DataControls", probablemente no has visto bien, pues si que los hay, tanto en VCL (TDBEdit, TDBNavigator, etc), como en FMX (Edit normal + Data Bindings, por ejemplo).

Comment: Los componentes datacontrols, deberían estar en la pestaña "Datacontrols" de tu paleta de componentes.

Comment: Efectivamente. En Vcl están los datacontrols. Dónde no los ví es en Fmx. Aunque seguramente debe haber varias alternativas que aún me son desconocidas. De todas formas el código anterior me es suficiente para realizar lo que requiero. Muchas gracias.

Comment: En FMX utilizas Live bindings para asociar los controles _normales_ a datos; es decir, usas el mismo TEdit, TCheckBox, y otros, y es el _motor_ de Live bindings el que hace el trabajo tras bambalinas. Hay una presentación sobre su uso en [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zeQFkHTGAOw)